# Is downloading .so (shared library files) on raspberry pi possible

Tags: software-installation, shared-libraries

I'm having a problem. I've installed & extracted the files for 7zip to my computer. But when I try to run 7zip with this command: `./7zz` [wich is the file that you extract from the .tar folder], I get: `./7zz: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. Can you guys [and gals] help me fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What does `file /usr/bin/7zz` tell you?

Comment: surely it would be `file ./7zz` since the OP is running `./7zz` :p

Answer (score 0):

If you had downloaded library files designed for the version of OS you have it should work if they were self contained and installed in the correct location.

Generally other files e.g. headers and dependencies are needed.

Library files are intended to be used by a compiled program NOT executed.

This is NOT normal practice. Applications normally are packaged into an installer e.g. a deb file.

There should be a 7zip application in the repository for your (unspecified) OS.

`sudo apt install 7zip` will install on *Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm* (there are slightly different packages in older OS).